# How to implement Keras custom loss function for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, loss-function

I have a multiclass classification problem and I'm using a LSTM to solve it. I've been training my model using `categorical_crossentropy`. But when it comes to checking the model quality (after training) I have to use this custom metric, where `A` is a 2D penalty matrix:

```
def score(y_true, y_pred):
    S = 0.0
    y_true = y_true.astype(int)
    y_pred = y_pred.astype(int)
    for i in range(0, y_true.shape[0]):
        S -= A[y_true[i], y_pred[i]]
    return S/y_true.shape[0]
```

Such custom metric can receive as input `y_true` and `y_pred` as Pandas `Series` objects, and it outputs a negative number which the closer to zero the better.

I'd like to replace the current `categorical_crossentropy` loss function with a custom loss that has a similar behaviour to the custom metric above, that is, considers the `A` penalty matrix.

The problems that I'm facing are that the inputs of a loss function are `Tensor` objects instead of Pandas `Series` objects, which I'm totally unfamiliar with. Not only that, but, as I'm dealing with a LSTM, the shape of my input Tensors are in 3D:

```
y_true: Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(1, 25131, 12), dtype=uint8)
type(y_true): <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
y_pred: Tensor("sequential_26/time_distributed_26/Reshape_1:0", shape=(1, 25131, 12), dtype=float32)
type(y_pred): <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

If it helps, this is my architecture:

```
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=25)]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value = 0.))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True, activation = "tanh")))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(12, activation='softmax')))
adam = adam_v2.Adam(learning_rate=0.002)

model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=score, metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=150, batch_size=1, shuffle=False,
                    validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=2, callbacks=[callbacks])
```

These are the shapes of my input data to the model, I have a total of 12 classes:

```py
print(f'{X_train.shape} {X_test.shape} {y_train.shape} {y_test.shape}')
(73, 25131, 29) (25, 23879, 29) (73, 25131, 12) (25, 23879, 12)
```

This is the `A` penalty matrix, size 12x12, which are the number of classes of the multiclass classification problem:

[image]

And this is the competition that I'm building the model for:

https://xeek.ai/challenges/force-well-logs/overview

https://github.com/bolgebrygg/Force-2020-Machine-Learning-competition/tree/master/lithology_competition

Comment: can we assumple A has shape (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[0]) ?

Comment: Penalty matrix `A` has shape 12x12 (which are the classes). I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to do model evaluation, you need a metric rather than a loss.

To convert your function to a custom metric in tensorflow:

1. Casting `y_true` and `y_pred` to `int` won't get what you want, you need to use `tf.argmax` instead, assuming that `y_true` are one-hot encoded labels and `y_pred` are probabilities. (because you used `categorical_crossentropy` to train and `softmax` as activation function in the output layer)
2. Define a custom metric class

Example Codes:

```
class Score(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
  def __init__(self, A, name="score", **kwargs):
    super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
    self.A = tf.constant(A,dtype=tf.float32)
    self.S = self.add_weight(name="S", initializer="zeros")
    self.num_elems = self.add_weight(name="num_elems", initializer="zeros")

  def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
    #convert y_true and y_pred to indices and flatten them
    y_true = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y_true,-1),(-1,))
    y_pred = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y_pred,-1),(-1,))
    num_elems = y_true.shape[0]
    indices = tf.stack([y_true,y_pred],1)
    #access A using indices and sum
    self.S.assign_add(-tf.reduce_sum(tf.gather_nd(self.A,indices)))
    self.num_elems.assign_add(num_elems)
        
  def result(self):
    return self.S/self.num_elems
```

Besides, `model.fit` is used to train the model. If you only want to evaluate the model, pass `Score()` as a metric and use `model.evaluate`.
Example Codes:

```
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(), 
              metrics=['accuracy',Score(A)])
model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=1)
```